# Permutations of a list of strings

Tags: java, permutation

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhotoLineups {
    public static void allPermutations(ArrayList<String> permList, ArrayList<String> nameList) {    
        if (nameList.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < permList.size(); i++) {
                if(i == permList.size()-1) {
                    System.out.print(permList.get(i));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(permList.get(i)+", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); ++i) {
                ArrayList<String> newPerm = new ArrayList<String>(permList);
                newPerm.add(nameList.get(i));
                ArrayList<String> newNameList = new ArrayList<String>(nameList);
                newNameList.remove(i);
                allPermutations(newPerm, newNameList);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> permList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String name;
        while (true) {
            name = scnr.next();
            if (name.equals("-1")) break;
            nameList.add(name);
        }

        allPermutations(permList, nameList);
    }
}
```

I get this 1 and only error when I run it on zyBooks:

```
Tests studentPhotos.printAllPermutations() correctly creates and outputs permutations
Compilation failed:
zyLabsUnitTest.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
      studentPhotos.printAllPermutations(permList, nameList);
                   ^
  symbol:   method printAllPermutations(ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>)
  location: variable studentPhotos of type PhotoLineups
1 error
```

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: There is no line `studentPhotos.printAllPermutations(permList, nameList);` in the code you posted.

Comment: I know, I'm not sure why its saying that when its giving me the error.

Comment: The posted code is running fine. While the posted error is not look like the error for the same code. I think you are **not using any IDE** and you are calling the method ***printAllPermutations()*** instead of ***allPermutations()*** using the object **studentPhotos** of ***PhotoLineups*** class like

    studentPhotos.printAllPermutations(permList, nameList);

**Note**: you can call static method directly inside main method without object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am editing this now that you added that comment.

From what I see in your error you are trying to call the method `printAllPermutations(ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>)` when that method does not exist. If I had to guess I would guess that wherever you calling the method you accidently typed `printAllPermutations` instead of `allPermutations`

Comment: I checked through it and I don't have anything with printAllPermutations

Comment: Is it possible that maybe the website you are trying to run this on wants the method to be named `printAllPermutations` instead of `allPermutations`?

Comment: I'll give that a shot quick.

Comment: @Moraban That seemed to do it, thank you very much!